# How to see Float value in ssms without exponential values?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, t-sql, ssms

I have inserted a  value in a table on float colum. And When I am seeing the record in ssms, it looks like exponential value.

For example, please execute the below query in ssms and see the output in SSMS. we could see the exponential value as output.

```
declare @l_float float = '1234567890123456789.12345'

select @l_float
```

Is any way possible to see the value as the same as declared value without convert to decimal or numeric?

For .NET, is this same output will get like we get in SSMS? (when they use double datatype too?)

Thanks in advance.

Regards,

Muthu

Comment: To give you a great answer, it might help us if you have a glance at [ask] if you haven't already. It might be also useful if you could provide a [mcve].

Comment: Bear in mind that a `float` only has a maximum of 15 digits of precision. You're never going to get back `1234567890123456789.12345`. The best you could hope for would be something like `1234567890123460000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: **Don't use `FLOAT` if you do not have a very good reason!**

And bear in mind, that **the value you *see* is not the actual value!**. It is a textual representation of a binary value a human could hardly understand / interpret.

With `FLOAT` and SSMS there are several issues:

1. `FLOAT` is not precise. It will be rounded somehow when shown somewhere or in calculations. You can alsways enforce the output using kind of formatting, but in this case you'd quite probably have to switch to string-level
2. Calculations with `FLOAT` tend to create silly *errors*, where you get numbers you would not expect (e.g. `0.00000003` instead of a pure `0`). In comparisons this can lead to hardly findable *bugs*...
3. SSMS will in most cases try to show a result in the *best* way to you. Depending on the values range this may vary from column to column...

If ever possible switch to `DECIMAL(x,y)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Could you please add demerits of this datatype? And here  why we are trying to use Float is for some some amount related columns we require more than 25 digits, for now it will be supported by Decimal. In future, if require to accommodate more than 38 digits, we require to change our code again. So we are checking with Float too. Thanks again.

Comment: @Muthu: Just google for something like `sql server float vs. decimal` and you will find tons of links. In short: `FLOAT` can handle a huge range. With tiny values you will get the most precise values, but with high (or huge) values you will get just an approximation. The bigger the less precise. It depends on your needs, but normally one should avoid `FLOAT`...